# SqlException IDENTITY_INSERT is set to off

Tags: sql, database, angular, api, azure

I am trying to insert a new `sportevent` with a sport and a `sporthall`. I am using a .NET core API that I am accessing from an Angular App. The values are submitted correctly:

[image]

But when I try to insert a `sportevent` (with a `sport` and `sporthall`) in my database I get this exception:

[image]

I have tried setting the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` with this command:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Sport ON;
```

My database is hosted on Azure.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?